# Import more than one dump file in oracle

Tags: oracle, import, oracle11g, dmp

I am using ORACLE 11g ORCL database. Can We import more than one dump file[for different users] at a time[using multiple command prompt] in Oracle database? Please suggest me, the procedure if possible the same..
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to import multiple user-level exports in different sessions simultaneously, sure.  You'd have the same sorts of contention issues that you'd get if you had two sessions that were both issuing a bunch of DDL and DML statements (library cache enqueue waits, contention for disk and CPU resources on the box, etc.)